# NightmareJS output on web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, nightmare

I am trying to get the output from nightmareJS out on a web page on button click 
using HTML CSS and JS.

My nightmareJS:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: false})

nightmare
  .goto('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux')

  //.wait('#entry-content')
  .evaluate(function () {
    var ht = document.querySelector('#toc > ul').innerText;
    //return ht[0];
    //return (ht.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).length);
    //check = document.querySelectorAll('#bodyblock > ul >li').length;
    //return check;
    //var ht1 = document.querySelectorAll('#bodyblock > ul > li ').innerText[5];
    //return ht1;
    return ht;


  })
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
     console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    return('Search failed:', error);
  });
```

I tried:
Example :

```
<script>
function scrapedData(){
  document.getElementById("nighmareJSOutput").innerHTML = result;
}
</script>

<body>

  <div>
    <p id="nighmareJSOutput"> </p>
    <button onclick="scrapedData()"> click me </button>

  </div>
```

this did not work either.

Any tips or suggestions please.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe try with some more words. `I tried the normal way of calling this js file in the <script> tag and it wouldn't work` means what exactly?

Comment: @DejanToteff sorry about that.

I have my javascript within my  <script> tags

like: 
<scripts>
var nightmare ....

</script>

<body>
<div id= "out">
</div>
</body>

My  goal is to get the output of my javascript ( nightmareJS scraped data)  into  <div> tag  so as to get it displayed on a web page.

Comment: @DejanToteff  edited my question : added the HTML format of what I tried.

Comment: Nightmare.js uses Electron and could be run only on server environment.

One way to accomplish what you want, is to send request to Express.js which would run Nightmare.js and return the result.

Do you need more explanation?

Comment: @DejanToteff  Thank you,  Yes please, if you can with a small example. 
The example need not work but a layout so I can understand what goes under which.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you the requested in the comments example. Ask questions if you still face issues.

```
const express = require('express')
const Nightmare = require("nightmare")
const app = express()

app.get('/', async function (req, res) {
  const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: false})
  const url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux'
  await nightmare.goto(url)
  await nightmare.wait(2000)
  const result = await nightmare.evaluate(
    () => document.querySelector('#toc > ul').innerText
  )
  res.send(result)
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Comment: am sorry I saw this late, I thought I would get an alert. I thought you forgot.
This was exactly what I was looking for. I can now build on this. Thanks alot!!